# search bar html css in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to use a search bar css from code pen. I used their exact code but the search bar seems to be really buggy on react.

Here is code sandbox for better reference. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-moser-mdxmd?file=/src/Dashboard.js

Here's the code that I am currently using.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="input_text"></input>
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: center;
  display: flex;
}

.searchTerm {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00b4cc;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9dbfaf;
}

.searchTerm:focus {
  color: #00b4cc;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00b4cc;
  background: #00b4cc;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap {
  width: 30%;
  position: flex;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I want the search bar to look like this: enter image description here

This is the link to the code that I attempted to use.

https://codepen.io/huange/pen/rbqsD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using simple html you have to use jsx here. Use any online jsx convertor like "https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm" etc.
for this you can use :

```html
<div className="wrap">
  <div className="search">
    <input type="text" className="searchTerm" id="input_text" />
    <button type="submit" className="searchButton">
      <i className="fa fa-search" />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```